# How do I set a custom response header in Feathers V5?

Tags: feathersjs

I need to set up an end point for Prometheus.  The end point requires a custom header:

"Content-Type": "text/plain; version=0.0.4; charset=utf-8"

I tried setting up a custom hook (see below), but all it does is add the Content Type to the body of the response.

```
export const setContentTypeHeader = (context: HookContext) => {
    context.result = {
        ...context.result,
        headers: {
        'X-Custom-Header': 'Hello World'
        }
    };
    // Set the custom header
    context.result.headers['Content-Type'] = promClient.register.contentType;
    console.log(context.result);
};
```

I use Feathers v5 and generated a metrics service using **feathers generate service**.

I also tried

```
app.use((req, res, next) => {
  res.setHeader('Server-Time', +new Date())
  next()
});
```

but the app object in v5 doesn't support this.

I use typescript and feathers with koa.

Answer (score 0):

You can modify the response headers by setting [context.http.headers](https://feathersjs.com/api/hooks.html#context-http) in your hook:

```
export const setContentTypeHeader = (context: HookContext) => {
    context.http.headers = {
        ...context.http.headers,
        headers: {
        'X-Custom-Header': promClient.register.contentType
        }
    };
};
```